# How to obtain random access of a gzip compressed file

Tags: python, indexing, gzip, random-access

According to [this FAQ on zlib.net](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_faq.html#faq28) it is possible to:

> access data randomly in a compressed stream

I know about the module Bio.bgzf of [Biopyton 1.60](http://news.open-bio.org/news/2012/06/biopython-1-60-released/), which:

> supports reading and writing BGZF files (Blocked GNU Zip Format), a variant of GZIP with efficient random access, most commonly used as part of the BAM file format and in tabix. This uses Python’s zlib library internally, and provides a simple interface like Python’s gzip library.

But for my use case I don't want to use that format. Basically I want something, which emulates the code below:

```
import gzip
large_integer_new_line_start = 10**9
with gzip.open('large_file.gz','rt') as f:
    f.seek(large_integer_new_line_start)
```

but with the efficiency offered by the native zlib.net to provide random access to the compressed stream. How do I leverage that random access capability in Python?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a bgzip compressed file? Bgzip is valid gzip...

Comment: @wkretzsch I do want to use bgzip. I asked the question more than 3 years ago, so I can't quite remember the details. Probably the files I was working with were gzipped and not bgzipped.

Answer (score 7):

I gave up on doing random access on a gzipped file using Python. Instead I converted my gzipped file to a block gzipped file with a [block compression/decompression utility](http://samtools.sourceforge.net/tabix.shtml) on the command line:

```
zcat large_file.gz | bgzip > large_file.bgz
```

Then I used [BioPython](http://biopython.org/) and tell to get the virtual_offset of line number 1 million of the bgzipped file. And then I was able to rapidly seek the virtual_offset afterwards:

```
from Bio import bgzf

file='large_file.bgz'

handle = bgzf.BgzfReader(file)
for i in range(10**6):
    handle.readline()
virtual_offset = handle.tell()
line1 = handle.readline()
handle.close()

handle = bgzf.BgzfReader(file)
handle.seek(virtual_offset)
line2 = handle.readline()
handle.close()

assert line1==line2
```

I would like to also point to the [SO answer by Mark Adler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14242594/778533) here on [examples/zran.c](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/zran.c) in the [zlib](http://zlib.net/) distribution.

Comment: Very useful, thanks for sharing the snippet! I will follow a similar path then. Considering that its a 9 years old post, please considering sharing if you have found a better option :D

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `dictzip.py`, part of the [serpento](http://kassiopeia.juls.savba.sk/~garabik/software/serpento/) package. However, you have to compress the files with `dictzip`, which is a random seekable backward compatible variant of the `gzip` compression.

Answer (score 0):

The [indexed_gzip](https://github.com/pauldmccarthy/indexed_gzip) program might be what you wanted. It also uses `zran.c` under the hood.

Answer (score -3):

If you just want to access the file from a random point can't you just do:

```
from random import randint

with open(filename) as f:
    f.seek(0, 2)
    size = f.tell()
    f.seek(randint(0, size), 2)
```

Comment: @scorpion-god Thanks. I don't want to read from a random point. I want the possibility to access any point in the gzip compressed file without having to read through the entire deflated stream.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen you can't teleport.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen More to the point: this is why they created BGZF because by default gzipped does not support this.  You still have to read the entire thing once to build an index.  More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225751/random-access-to-gzipped-files

Comment: @metatoaster Thanks. I don't mind reading the entire thing once to build an index. I will use BGZF, if I can figure out how to use it on any file format of my choice. It seems to be restricted to a pre-selected set of file formats.